# R: how to get max value of a column from rows with specific condition

Tags: r

I imported a table like this:

[image]

I need to get the european country with more total cases.
How do i filter only the rows where continent="Europe" and get the row with max(total_cases)?

Thank you

Comment: try grouping first!

Comment: I have this but i only get the max() and not the name of the country
max(total_cases[continent=="Europe"], na.rm=TRUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
           filter(Continent == 'Europe') %>%
           filter(Total_cases == max(Total_cases, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or in base R :

```
result <- subset(subset(df, Continent == 'Europe'), 
                  Total_cases == max(Total_cases, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: thank you. both solutions solved my problem